# Posting attribute/field values by points on the map view

Tags: qgis, mapview

To see a attributes/field values of point(s) or a polygon most usually  is to select (i) icon and then clicking on a point or a polygon and then table with values shows on the right.

Is it possible to post attribute/field data by the points/polygons in the map view (up-right corner of the point itself)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use labels for showing the value of an attribute on the upper left corner of your points, see screenshot below for details:

1. Go to the label tab of your layer
2. Select the attribute you want to show near your points (in the screenshot, you see I selected `fid`)
3. Go to the Placement tab and select as mode `Offset from Point`
4. Select the upper left `Quadrant`
5. If the label is to close to your points, change the `X,Y Offset` values (in the screenshot, my X offset is -1, Y offset is 0)

[image]

Comment: It works. Many thanks.

Comment: will try to find "ACCEPT"